# Difference between an AD server and a CAS server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, cas

This is perhaps a dumb question, but I am entirely new in this area and I apologize in advance if it is.

I understand the relationship between Active Directory and LDAP (i.e. LDAP is a protocol that a database based system like Active Directory may use to perform authentication tasks).

However, what does a Central Authentication Service (CAS) Server need to have in addition to an AD to support SSO? Essentially, I'm trying to find out what's the difference between an LDAP server that runs AD and a CAS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially Active Directory is a directory server by Microsoft that is accessible over LDAP. LDAP is an open standard protocol for accessing directory servers.

CAS is a server for authenticating users and providing single sign on across disparate clients.  CAS can use Active Directory as a source for authentications.  CAS can also use LDAP to authenticate users against LDAP capable directory servers.

Have you seen this page? It will hopefully illustrate the overall architecture for you.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/planning/Architecture.html